# Universal Windows 10.16299 Windows Runtime Component build error

Tags: c#, uwp, realm, windows-10-universal

I've written a Xamarin UWP (Universal Windows) app targeting Windows 10 build 16299. Currently I'm syncing data within the app and storing it in a realm database for offline use. I would like to move the sync code to a background task so it can run it in a schedule, updating data in the background. I added a new project of type Windows Runtime Component also targeting Windows 10 build 16299. Added realm and newtonsoft.json as nuget packages. When I try to build the project I get a build error. How can I solve the error?

Sample project can be found here https://github.com/GuidoNeele/RealmWindowsRuntimeComponentTest

Build output

```
ExportWindowsMDFile:
  C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\v15.0\AppxPackage\winmdexp.exe /mp:obj\x86\Debug\RealmTest.UWP.BackgroundSync.compile.pdb
  /pdb:obj\x86\Debug\RealmTest.UWP.BackgroundSync.pdb
  /out:obj\x86\Debug\RealmTest.UWP.BackgroundSync.winmd
  /utf8output
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.CSharp.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.VisualBasic.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\Microsoft.Win32.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\mscorlib.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\netstandard.dll
  /reference:C:\Users\guido\.nuget\packages\newtonsoft.json\11.0.1\lib\netstandard2.0\Newtonsoft.Json.dll
  /reference:C:\Users\guido\.nuget\packages\realm.databinding\1.2.0\lib\netstandard1.0\Realm.DataBinding.dll
  /reference:C:\Users\guido\.nuget\packages\realm.database\2.2.0\lib\netstandard1.4\Realm.dll
  /reference:C:\Users\guido\.nuget\packages\realm\2.2.0\lib\netstandard1.4\Realm.Sync.dll
  /reference:C:\Users\guido\.nuget\packages\remotion.linq\2.1.2\lib\portable-net45+win+wpa81+wp80\Remotion.Linq.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.AppContext.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Buffers.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Collections.Concurrent.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Collections.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Collections.Immutable.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Collections.NonGeneric.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Collections.Specialized.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ComponentModel.Annotations.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ComponentModel.Composition.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ComponentModel.DataAnnotations.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ComponentModel.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ComponentModel.EventBasedAsync.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ComponentModel.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ComponentModel.TypeConverter.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Configuration.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Console.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Core.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Data.Common.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Data.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Data.SqlClient.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.Contracts.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.Debug.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.FileVersionInfo.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.Process.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.StackTrace.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.TextWriterTraceListener.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.Tools.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.TraceSource.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Diagnostics.Tracing.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Drawing.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Drawing.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Dynamic.Runtime.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Globalization.Calendars.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Globalization.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Globalization.Extensions.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.Compression.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.Compression.FileSystem.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.Compression.ZipFile.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.FileSystem.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.FileSystem.DriveInfo.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.FileSystem.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.FileSystem.Watcher.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.IsolatedStorage.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.MemoryMappedFiles.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.Pipes.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.Ports.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.IO.UnmanagedMemoryStream.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Linq.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Linq.Expressions.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Linq.Parallel.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Linq.Queryable.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.Http.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.Http.Rtc.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.HttpListener.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.Mail.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.NameResolution.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.NetworkInformation.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.Ping.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.Requests.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.Security.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.ServicePoint.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.Sockets.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.WebClient.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.WebHeaderCollection.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.WebProxy.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.WebSockets.Client.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Net.WebSockets.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Numerics.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Numerics.Vectors.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Numerics.Vectors.WindowsRuntime.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ObjectModel.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Reflection.Context.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Reflection.DispatchProxy.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Reflection.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Reflection.Extensions.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Reflection.Metadata.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Reflection.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Reflection.TypeExtensions.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Resources.Reader.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Resources.ResourceManager.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Resources.Writer.dll
  /reference:C:\Users\guido\.nuget\packages\system.runtime.compilerservices.unsafe\4.4.0\ref\netstandard2.0\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.Unsafe.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.CompilerServices.VisualC.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.Extensions.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.Handles.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.InteropServices.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.InteropServices.RuntimeInformation.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.InteropServices.WindowsRuntime.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.Numerics.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.Serialization.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.Serialization.Json.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.Serialization.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.Serialization.Xml.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Runtime.WindowsRuntime.UI.Xaml.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.AccessControl.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Claims.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Cryptography.Algorithms.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Cryptography.Cng.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Cryptography.Csp.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Cryptography.Encoding.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Cryptography.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Principal.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.Principal.Windows.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Security.SecureString.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ServiceModel.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ServiceModel.Duplex.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ServiceModel.Http.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ServiceModel.NetTcp.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ServiceModel.Primitives.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ServiceModel.Security.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ServiceModel.Web.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ServiceProcess.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Text.Encoding.CodePages.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Text.Encoding.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Text.Encoding.Extensions.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Text.RegularExpressions.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.Overlapped.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.Tasks.Dataflow.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.Tasks.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.Thread.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.ThreadPool.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Threading.Timer.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Transactions.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Transactions.Local.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.ValueTuple.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Web.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Web.HttpUtility.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Windows.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.Linq.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.ReaderWriter.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.Serialization.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.XDocument.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.XmlDocument.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.XmlSerializer.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.XPath.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\System.Xml.XPath.XDocument.dll
  /reference:<nuget path>\microsoft.netcore.universalwindowsplatform\6.0.8\ref\uap10.0.15138\WindowsBase.dll
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract\2.0.0.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.Calls.CallsVoipContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.SocialInfo.SocialInfoContract\2.0.0.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.SocialInfo.SocialInfoContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTaskContract\2.0.0.0\Windows.ApplicationModel.StartupTaskContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDeviceContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Devices.Custom.CustomDeviceContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Devices.DevicesLowLevelContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Devices.Printers.PrintersContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Devices.Printers.PrintersContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardBackgroundTriggerContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardBackgroundTriggerContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract\5.0.0.0\Windows.Devices.SmartCards.SmartCardEmulatorContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract\3.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.FoundationContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract\5.0.0.0\Windows.Foundation.UniversalApiContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Gaming.XboxLive.StorageApiContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Gaming.XboxLive.StorageApiContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract\4.0.0.0\Windows.Graphics.Printing3D.Printing3DContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Networking.Connectivity.WwanContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract\2.0.0.0\Windows.Services.Store.StoreContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.Services.TargetedContent.TargetedContentContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.Services.TargetedContent.TargetedContentContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileHardwareTokenContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileHardwareTokenContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileSharedModeContract\2.0.0.0\Windows.System.Profile.ProfileSharedModeContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\References\10.0.16299.0\Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewManagementViewScalingContract\1.0.0.0\Windows.UI.ViewManagement.ViewManagementViewScalingContract.winmd
  /reference:<Windows Kits Path>\10\UnionMetadata\facade\Windows.winmd
  obj\x86\Debug\RealmTest.UWP.BackgroundSync.winmdobj
WINMDEXP : error WME1007: Could not resolve reference 'Assembly(Name=System.Collections, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)'.

Build FAILED.


"C:\DEV\Test\Realm\RealmTest\RealmTest.UWP.BackgroundSync\RealmTest.UWP.BackgroundSync.csproj" (default target) (1) ->
(ExportWindowsMDFile target) -> 
  WINMDEXP : error WME1007: Could not resolve reference 'Assembly(Name=System.Collections, Version=4.2.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a)'.

    1 Warning(s)
    1 Error(s)

Time Elapsed 00:00:01.22
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

Comment: According to your description, it's hard to diagnose this issue. Please upload a [mcve] for us to test it.

Comment: @xavier-xie-msft I've added a sample project to make my issue more clear. https://github.com/GuidoNeele/RealmWindowsRuntimeComponentTest

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm using Shiny (https://github.com/shinyorg/shiny) to run background tasks.

Answer (score 0):

The realm official document has explained it:

> Note for UWP, .NET Core and other .NET Standard projects: due to changes in NuGet 3.1, packages are no longer able to create content files, so FodyWeavers.xml will not be created automatically. You’ll need to manually create the file and paste the content above. Please refer to [this post](https://github.com/Fody/UniversalAppSample/blob/master/readme.md) for more information.

I followed these steps on that post and successfully compile my UWP runtime component.

1. `install-package Fody`
2. manually add this FodyWeavers.xml file to your project
3. `install-package Fielder.Fody` and `install-package PropertyChanged.Fody`
4. Add weavers to xml
5. Add PropertyChanged to xml

***[Updated on 3/28/2018]***

[image]

[image]

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<Weavers>
  <Fielder/>
  <PropertyChanged/>
</Weavers>
```

Comment: As I understand it you just need to add the FodyWeavers.xml manually, instead of previously automatically via nuget, and add the <RealmWeaver/> in. I don't see how installing Fody and weavers will solve the build error. I tried what you said but sadly it didn't work.

Comment: Would be interested in your build log to see which references are being used. I've set my build output to normal instead of minimal to see the ExportWindowsMDFile kick off.

Comment: @xavier-xie-msft Could you add <RealmWeaver /> to the XML file? Without it the project builds, but if you include it the build will fail.

Comment: Having the same issue as @GuidoNeele, anyone found a solution?